# Is it ok to bring sex toy in South Korea? In luggages

Tags: air-travel, south-korea, china-southern-airlines

I'd like to know if it’s possible to take two vibrators into South Korea. I'll be flying from USA to China and will connect there to South Korea.

Comment: I cannot answer for China but sextoys are legal in South Korea: there are sexshops in plain sight downtown in Busan and Seoul, and online shops like Gmarkets sell them.

Answer (score 3):

A UK sex toy company has a very helpful [blog post](https://carvakasextoys.co.uk/blog/sex-toys-ban-around-the-world) listing the countries where sex toys are banned. This list is:

1. Saudi Arabia
2. United Arab Emirates
3. The Maldives
4. Thailand
5. Vietnam
6. Malaysia
7. India

No problems in either China or South Korea. In general, it is recommended to put your toy in a clear plastic bag so if your bags are checked by a security officer they can without touching it -- neither you neither they want that. And remove batteries. If there are wires, coil them separately from the toy. The last thing on earth you want is an object with wires wrapped around it to show up on a scanner. I had a mate whose big stash of chocolate mixed up with charging cables, causing a genuine bomb scare.

Comment: That list is incomplete: for example, realistic sex toys are banned in Singapore, which is not listed.

Comment: I can confirm the legality of sex toys in China--I've seen multiple sex toy shops there, sometimes placed inside drug stores (although these were always large places that sold a lot more than just medicine.)  The illegality of pornography means the packaging is tame by US standards.